# Azure AD B2C - Microsoft Account - login.live.com - deprecated

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The following [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-msa-idp) uses login.live.com to sign the user, but isn't this considered deprecated?
Are there any samples to connect using Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) to sign users in with their Microsoft personal accounts.

Specifically, you can use the `consumers` tenant, so that only users with a Microsoft personal account can sign in to your Azure AD B2C tenant:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/v2.0`

An example of this can be found in [the Woodgrove Groceries sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo).

See [the "Microsoft Personal Account" claims provider](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/blob/2b5110c25d1a626bf9b9ac27ecaaabad8b4bccf4/Policies/B2C_1A_base.xml#L758) for more information.

Comment: This seems exactly what I need. I will try it at the end of the week. Thank you.